# Get Coordinates of Screen when user touched

Tags: swift

I want to get the **coordinates** of screen when user touched it. 
I try touchesBegan Method but when i am using NSSet as a parameter i get an error. Can anyone guide me where am i mistaken how to solve this.

Thanks in advance...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject()! as! UITouch
    lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
}
```

**Error**: Overriding method with selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent)'

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
let touch = touches.first() as? UITouch
```

Comment: No this is not working...
**Error** : NSSet does not have a member named first